# How to pass a variable to all file

Tags: php, file, variables

i have this variable $date in my first page. any possibility to pass it in all my php file?

something like this?

```
<form action = 'insert.php' method="post"  >

        <p><input type="submit" name="ok"value="Terminé" id="end"></p>
        <?php $_POST['date']=$date ?>
       </form>
```

my other page

```
if (isset($_POST['date']))    
{ 
$date = $_GET['date'];
echo($date);
}
```

Comment: Start by spacing this out `name="ok"value="Terminé"` to `name="ok" value="Terminé"`

Comment: use ";" in <?php $_POST['date']; = $date ?>

Comment: make change and my echo not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form action = 'insert.php' method="post"  >
<p>
<input type="submit" name="ok" value="Terminé" id="end" />
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" />
</p>
</form>
```

You can then recive it with

```
$_POST['data']
```

---

Alternatively use [$_SESSION](http://www.php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.session.php).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `global` variable like

```
global $variable_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

include the file that has the data variable in the other files

```
include "file.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $SESSION, $GLOBAL. I'll not propose to you to use hidden field in html because it will be dangerous.

If you need this var only for this form you can create a form class into the session which contains this varaible such as. Here you nedd to write your own Form class.

```
$frmTest = new Form();
$frmTest->AddVar($date); //Add your date here
$_SESSION['frmTest']= $frmTest;
```

You can get easily this variable in the next page.

Comment: If i have 40 input in my page, can I send to my insert.php my 40 value the client enter in my input ?

Comment: cause when i do it my function autocomplete won'T work ( my function work with enter pressed) and when i do it for post in all my code when i press enter its refresh